# How to send number of images to server using JSON Array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, afnetworking, image-uploading

I'm facing a problem in sending Images to the server . I'm trying to save the list of Images in the `base64` encryption format string into **each object of array** and  I have to send the array to the server , but when I try to send multiple images , this thing does not work and only one or no image are uploaded to the server and sometimes all image are uploaded  . Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this using `AFNetworking` or any any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)uploadPhoto{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.url"]];

    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.avatarView.image, 0.5);


    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": self.username, @"password" : self.password};


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:paramNameForImage fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];

    [operation start];

}
```